# Instaling Red5 onWindows 2012 x64

Tags: red5

I am trying to install red5 1.01 on windows server x64 with java se 7

i follwed this

http://juankpro.com/wordpress/2011/01/26/what-is-and-how-to-install-red5-in-windows/

Now, if i install to ip 127.0.0.1:5080

i can see the video (saying your are working).

but if i put the servers ip in with :5080 (externaly) i get nothing.

So  if i install iwht server ip.  i can acesss it from external  and internal (but this video sayoing working is not there i get a blank screen

cananyone throuw and light on this please.

also i canot get the deoms to install. :} there java 6,  i dont want to install j6 for obviuos reason.

Comment: Maybe your firewall or antivirus is blocking access to the port 5080?

Comment: Use the latest release and install jdk 8 x64

Answer (score 0):

just bind ip with 0.0.0.0 then port forward with required port let say 5080 etc., appart from the allow the Red5 with behind the firewall., thats it now everybody can able to see you...

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your answer doesn't have a lot of detail, so if you edited your answer to include the steps to do said binding, that would help the OP a great deal more.